# 100% CPU on gnome-shell

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, gnome-shell-extension

Twice a day the gnome-shell is stuck on 100% overlloading one of the core.
Killing the process seems to provide a temp solution.

How can I find the reason for this issue?